# Replace special characters with space in search box

Tags: php, string, replace, character

i have a search box in php file, like this

```
<form action="/">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input class="submit" type="submit"  value="Search" />
</form>
```

but the search gets screwed up if user enters special characters in search box.

so how can i replace the special characters with space before it gets passed to the search?.

thanks for your time.

Comment: how can i replace it as i dont have any variable ?

Comment: also what if user enters 2 special characters like this $$ so it shouldnt create 2 blank spaces .

Comment: Can you elaborate on "screwed up"? Also, provide some PHP that shows what you do with the data from the form.

Comment: You are posting the form to the same script that contains the form. Pick the value of q up in $_GET["q"] in PHP. From there on, do a search. What is the problem?

Comment: @ErwinMoller If you use a framework like codeigniter it simply won't allow certain characters in the url.
Using post would solve a lot, but if he wan'ts a javascript solution that can work too.

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out by others, it'd probably be best to perform the validation and filtering on the server side for security reasons (for example, a user could simply write special characters into the query part of the URL)

Something like this may do, which will replace all characters that are not alpha numeric to spaces;

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', ' ', $q);
```

Comment: why not simply `$q = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', ' ', $_GET['q']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/">
<input type="text" name="q" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(new RegExp('(a|b|d)', 'g'), ' ');">
<input class="submit" type="submit"  value="Search" />
</form>
```

Just change the a|b|d in your characters you want to replace.

Or, you could change from a GET form submit to POST

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input class="submit" type="submit"  value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Doing something client side to prevent the server side not to crash isn't very foolproof.

Comment: That's why I also suggest the post method. Then you bypass invalid URI elements errors of some frameworks. All roads lead to rome, some are better than others...

Comment: Who said anything about invalid URI? This question is far to ambiguous to be answered in any reasonable manner, in my opinion.

Comment: And you, expect a beginning programmer to immediately understand all programming basics? There is a learning curve to everything you know? Not everyone is an experienced programmer or knows how to format a question well enough. It's something you need to learn, and we need to have patience with. I for one don't believe it's ambiguous.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to understand anything, but I do expect people to put an effort into their questions. Tagging a question with `php` without providing any, and only describing the error as "screwed up" just doesn't cut it for me. But then again, I'm not forced to read the question. Apparent lack of effort just bugs me.

Comment: I totally sympathise, but then I remember the time when I started programming with books I bought from the bookstore about php and html on my lap and not being able to make head or tails from it, let alone make clear to anyone what I wanted to accomplish. With age comes understanding and wisdom... or you become a script kiddy, leeching of everyone's elses accomplishments, changing strings but not code your own code...

Comment: Plus, his question was specific how to do it client side. Who am I to argue with bad coding habits? I need to give the consortium of hacking housewifes in the netherlands also a chance to find exploits in websites... what would the world be without sql injection...

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to go for a regular expression (regex)